# Location Based 3D

Tags: 3d, location, augmented-reality

I want to know whether there are a software that a free and open source that can display 3D by using location-based. For example, I have a 3D buildings in glb format. The 3D buildings has a fixed coordinates. So when i walk with my mobile to the surrounding, the 3D buildings will display based on their coordinates. If it are not their coordinates, it will not display.

I try to create using OpenSpace3D but i can't find any solution. I am new to this field so if anybody know please tell me. I am stuck with my project.

Thank you.